# Remove Pending tests from mochawesome report

Tags: cypress, mochawesome

I am using cypress-select-tests module to filter cypress tests.

The issue is unselected tests are marked as pending in mochawesome report which doesn't look good.

How can I remove the pending tests from the Report?

Comment: It depends on how you have set up mochawesome reporting. If you are using `cypress-mochawesome-reporter` then a fairly simple script can be run on the json rsults between running the tests and running the report.

Comment: Note that the pending flag is a mocha thing - not specific to `cypress-select-tests`. If you manually `it.skip()` you will also get the pending output.

Answer (score 0):

You can move them to a different folder and add them to ["ignoreTestFiles" in cypress.config.json](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Global). This works for me, when I had the same problem